# org mode agenda ignore entries with no TODO state

Tags: org-mode

I have the following (sub)tree in an org file

```
* Project
** SubProject
*** TODO Do this action 1
*** TODO Do this action 2
```

I want my agenda to only show the entries with a TODO keyword. Currently the agenda gives me

```
Project
SubProject
TODO Do this action 1
TODO Do this action 2
```

I want it to show only

```
TODO Do this action 1
TODO Do this action 2
```

Currently I use `org-agenda-skip-function-global` to skip `DONE` and `CANCELLED` actions

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-function-global 
      '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo '("DONE" "CANCELLED")))
```

Is there a way to tell this to also skip actions with no TODO state? I've tried adding `nil` or `""` but that doesn't work? If not, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What are you using for the agenda View?  None of the default ones display `Project` or `SubProject`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the condition `nottodo` for an inverted match and use:

```
(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'nottodo '("TODO"))
```

Use `C-h f org-agenda-skip-if RET` to see the full documentation.